# The set of all fixed points of a continuous function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ , satisfying $f \circ f=f$ , is a non-empty interval?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ be a continuous function such that $f \circ f=f$ on $[0,1]$ , then is it true that the set $\{x \in [0,1] : f(x)=x \}$ is a non-empty interval?

---

I can show that it is non-empty as for any $x\in [0,1]$,$f(f(x))=f(x)$ so every point of $f([0,1])$ is a fixed point. I think I can show that $\{x\in [0,1]:f(x)=x\}=f([0,1])$. But proving it is an interval is appearing difficult for me.

Comment: Have you tried assuming it isn't and then finding a contradiction?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I can show that it is non-empty as for any $x \in [0,1] , f(f(x))=f(x)$ so every point of $f([0,1])$ is a fixed point , but proving interval is appearing difficult for me ....

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : Oh yes , I think I can show that $\{x \in [0,1] : f(x)=x \}=f([0,1])$ . am I correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $\{x \in [0, 1]: f(x) = x\}$ is just the image of $f$,which is an interval by the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

My proof : 
let $g(x)=f(x)-x$ which is clearly continuous , $g(0)=f(0)\geq 0$ and $g(1)=f(1)-1\leq 0$ hence by the IVT there is $c \in [0,1]$ such that $g(c)=f(c)-c=0$ hence $c\in E=\{x \in [0,1] | f(x)=x \}$  , now let $x,y \in E$ such that $x\leq y$ , for $t\in[0,1]$ let $z=(1-t)x+ty$ , we have $f(x)=x\leq z \leq y=f(y)$ by the IVT again  there $h\in [0,1]$ such that $z=f(h)$ but since $f(f(h))=f(h)$ we get $f(z)=z$ hence $E$ is a convex part of $\mathbb{R}$  , and so  $E$ is an interval .